# How can I force to specific folder/file to include to check-in in GitHub and VS 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github-for-windows

I am using github built-in ignore list in VS
https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Problem is I have one folder which is part of project named as 'Debug' Github also ignoring it and also certificate

How can I force to specific folder/file to include in check-in in GitHub and VS 2015?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just have to add an exception for that specific folder.
Assuming you want all files in that folder commited, you'll add this:

```
!**/AdminPanel/Debug/
```